# franka_ros message meaning

Tags: ros-noetic, rosmessage

Has anyone ever tried to understand the meaning of each parameter in [FrankaState.msg](https://github.com/frankaemika/franka_ros/blob/5f90395ef000e0c998fb7aff8f127b9bd3773962/franka_msgs/msg/FrankaState.msg)? After reading the official documentation, I only understand some of them, such as `O_T_EE` and `F_T_EE`. What do the rest of these parameters mean and how do I find out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The explanation has been found in [there](https://frankaemika.github.io/libfranka/structfranka_1_1RobotState.html).

**EDIT**:

`O_T_EE`: Measured end-effector pose in base frame.

`O_T_EE_d`: Last desired end-effector pose of motion generation in the base frame.

`F_T_EE`: End-effector frame pose in flange frame.

`F_T_NE`: Nominal end-effector frame pose in flange frame.

`NE_T_EE`: End-effector frame pose in nominal end-effector frame.

`EE_T_K`: Stiffness frame pose in end-effector frame.

`m_ee`: Configured mass of the end effector.

`I_ee`: Configured rotational inertia matrix of the end effector load with respect to center of mass.

`F_x_Cee`: Configured center of mass of the end effector load with respect to flange frame.

`m_load`: Configured mass of the external load.

`I_load`: Configured rotational inertia matrix of the external load with respect to center of mass.

`F_x_Cload`: Configured center of mass of the external load with respect to flange frame.

`m_total`: Sum of the mass of the end effector and the external load.

`I_total`: Combined rotational inertia matrix of the end effector load and the external load with respect to the center of mass.

`F_x_Ctotal`: Combined center of mass of the end effector load and the external load with respect to flange frame.

`elbow`: Elbow configuration.

`elbow_d`: Desired elbow configuration.

`elbow_c`: Commanded elbow configuration.

`delbow_c`: Commanded elbow velocity.

`ddelbow_c`: Commanded elbow acceleration.

`tau_J`: Measured link-side joint torque sensor signals.

`tau_J_d`: Desired link-side joint torque sensor signals without gravity.

`dtau_J`: Derivative of measured link-side joint torque sensor signals.

`q`: Measured joint position.

`q_d`: Desired joint position.

`dq`: Measured joint velocity.

`dq_d`: Desired joint velocity.

`ddq_d`: Desired joint acceleration.